# Java Streams: group a List into a Map of Maps

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How could I do the following with Java Streams?

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class Foo {
    Bar b;
}

class Bar {
    String id;
    String date;
}
```

I have a `List<Foo>` and I want to convert it to a `Map <Foo.b.id, Map<Foo.b.date, Foo>`. I.e: *group first by the `Foo.b.id` and then by `Foo.b.date`*.

I'm struggling with the following 2-step approach, but the second one doesn't even compile:

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> groupById =
        myList
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                foo -> foo.getBar().getId()
                        )
                );

Map<String, Map<String, Foo>> output = groupById.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(
                entry -> entry.getKey(),
                entry -> entry.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.groupingBy(
                                        bar -> bar.getDate()
                                )
                        )
        );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, are you sure every element in the list will be unique? That is, an id and a date will give exactly a single `Foo` object?

Comment: Do you want a `Map <Foo.b.id, Map<Foo.b.date, Foo.b>` or a `Map <Foo.b.id, Map<Foo.b.date, List<Foo.b>>` ?

Comment: @Eran you're right, edited :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can group your data in one go assuming there are only distinct `Foo`:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Foo>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(f -> f.b.id, 
                 Collectors.toMap(f -> f.b.date, Function.identity())));
```

Saving some characters by using static imports:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Foo>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(f -> f.b.id, toMap(f -> f.b.date, identity())));
```

Answer (score 5):

Suppose `(b.id, b.date)` pairs are distinct. If so,
in second step you don't need grouping, just collecting to `Map` where key is `foo.b.date` and value is `foo` itself:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Foo>> map = 
       myList.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(f -> f.b.id))    // map {Foo.b.id -> List<Foo>}
             .entrySet().stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(),                 // id
                                       e -> e.getValue().stream()       // stream of foos
                                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f.b.date, 
                                                                       f -> f))));
```

Or even more simple:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Foo>> map = 
       myList.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(f -> f.b.id, 
                                            Collectors.toMap(f -> f.b.date, 
                                                             f -> f)));
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for the comments in the code. I didn't realize a map was created after a `collect(Collectros.groupingBy())`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to support the equality contract on your key, `Bar`:

```
class Bar {
    String id;
    String date;

    public boolean equals(Object o){
       if (o == null) return false;
       if (!o.getClass().equals(getClass())) return false;
       Bar other = (Bar)o;
       return Objects.equals(o.id, id) && Objects.equals(o.date, date);
    }

    public int hashCode(){
       return id.hashCode*31 + date.hashCode;
    }    
}
```

Now you can just have a `Map<Bar, Foo>`.

Comment: OP definitely wants `Bar`s with the same `id` but different `date` also be stored, but in your approach they will be thrown away. Another flaw in your code is null-unsafe way of comparing `id`s-- `Objects.equals()` is much better for this. And I cannot understand what is the purpose of comparing `o.date` to `this.id`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou First statement is not true, you can have same ids and different dates using this method. And as for nulls, Map doesn't allow null keys, so I assume they have none. Third point is a typo, which probably affects the first point too!

Comment: Yes, your edit made equality based on `id` and `date`, not `id` only. Now to search for `Foo` you need to create dummy `Bar` object--it certainly may be an approach. +1

Comment: @SashaSalauyou yes that is true. But I would rather that than a map of maps, unless I wanted to perform a partial lookup, i.e. lookup all that match an `id`