# Collecting duplicates using a Java 8 stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a list of `cats`, and I want to group the `cats` with same `colour` and group them by `owner`. How do I do this in Java 8?

```
public class Cat{
    private String name;
    private Owner owner;
    private String color;
    public Cat(String name,Owner owner,String color){
        this.name=name;
        this.owner= owner;
        this.color= color;
    }
}

public class Owner{
    private String name;
    public Owner(String name){
        this.name= name;
    } 
}
```

Lets say I have following data:

```
Owner owner1= new Owner("John");  Owner owner2= new Owner("Smith");
Owner owner3= new Owner("Scott"); 
Cat cat1 = new Cat ("Cat1",owner1,"Brown"); 
Cat cat2 = new Cat ("Cat2",owner2,"Black");
Cat cat3 = new Cat ("Cat3",owner1,"Brown");
Cat cat4 = new Cat ("Cat4",owner3,"White");

List<Cat> catList = new ArrayList<>();
catList.add(cat1);
catList.add(cat2);
catList.add(cat3);
catList.add(cat4);
```

I am expecting map of `owner1` which has two cats, `owner2` has 1 , `owner3` has 1 cat.

Comment: What do you mean with "collect the cats with same colour". You want to group by colour and owner, or you want to filter by a specific colour?

Comment: First try to do your task with plain loops so you can see the algorithm, which can be transformed into the `Stream` API. It seems like you have to do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33254512/4105457

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) with the appropriate getter method:

```
Map<Owner, List<Cat>> byOwner = catList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cat::getOwner));
// {Owner(name=John)=[Cat(name=Cat1), Cat(name=Cat3)], Owner(name=Scott)=[Cat(name=Cat4)], Owner(name=Smith)=[Cat(name=Cat2)]}

Map<String, List<Cat>> byColor = catList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cat::getColor));
// {Brown=[Cat(name=Cat1), Cat(name=Cat3)], White=[Cat(name=Cat4)], Black=[Cat(name=Cat2)]}
```