# Java 8 List<Foo> to Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have following class:

```
public class Foo {
    private String areaName;
    private String objectName;
    private String lineName;
}
```

Now I want to convert a `List<Foo>` to `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33254512/7109162) which helped me develop following code:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> testMap = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getAreaName(),
        Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getObjectName(), Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                e -> e.stream().map(f -> f.getLineName())))));
```

The only problem with this code is the part where it should convert to `List<String>`. I couldn't find a way to convert `Foo` to `List` in that part.

Another approach which results in `Map<String, Map<String, List<Foo>>>`:

```
Map<Object, Map<Object, List<Foo>>> testMap = ventures.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getAreaName(),
        Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getObjectName(), Collectors.toList())));
```

**What do I need to change in order to receive `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>` from `List<Foo>`?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to get a `List` of a different type than the type of the `Stream` elements, you should chain a `Collectors.mapping` collector to `groupingBy`:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> testMap = 
    foos.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getAreaName,
                                       Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getObjectName,
                                                             Collectors.mapping(Foo::getLineName,
                                                                                Collectors.toList()))));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe i didn't see `Collectors::mapping` method!