# Java8 generate Map containing another Map

Tags: java-8

How do I achieve this using java=8

I have a CSV in below format and from this i want to populate `Map<String, Map<String, String>`
where the outer map will have key `scriptId` and `transationType` as these are the distinct `Type` and inner map for `scriptId` key should contain first 5 values stating from position 2 as key and 3 as value.

```
<scriptId<
      <TATA,TATA Moters>
      <REL,Reliance Industries Ltd>
      <LNT, L&T>
      <SBI, State Bank of India>>
 <transactionType,<
       <P,B>
       <S,S>>
```

Content of CSV File

```
Type,ArcesiumValue,GICValue
scriptId,TATA,TATA Moters
scriptId,REL,Reliance Industries Ltd
scriptId,LNT,L&T
scriptId,SBI,State Bank of India
transactionType,P,B
transactionType,S,S
```

How do i generate this using Java8

```
public void loadReferenceData() throws IOException {

        List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> cache = Files.lines(Paths.get("data/referenceDataMapping.csv")).skip(1)
                .map(mapRefereneData).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(cache);

    }

    public static Function<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> mapRefereneData = (line) -> {
        String[] sp = line.split(",");
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> cache = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        try {
            if (cache.containsKey(sp[0])) {
                cache.get(sp[0]).put(sp[1], sp[2]);
            } else {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(sp[1], sp[2]);
                cache.put(sp[0], map);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cache;
    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Streams: group a List into a Map of Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253858/java-streams-group-a-list-into-a-map-of-maps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it is much simpler to use two `Collectors`:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> groupCSV = Files.lines(Paths.get("..."))
    .skip(1L).map(l -> l.split(","))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], Collectors.toMap(a -> a[1], a -> a[2])));
```