# How to Collect my java object in Map<String, Map<String,String>> format?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I am trying to split my Java Object to a collection and couldn't get around it.

Currently my java object has 1:1:Many mapping

```
Student{
String name;
String shoeSize;
String Color;
}
```

The data looks like this

[image]

I intend to convert this to something like this

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this using Java Streams?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDakw.png)

Comment: check this url -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253858/java-streams-group-a-list-into-a-map-of-maps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Streams: group a List into a Map of Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253858/java-streams-group-a-list-into-a-map-of-maps)

Comment: Does each person have only one shoe size? If so, size should be an attribute on the person object, and instead of a nested map use a nested set/list of sizes. `record Student ( String name , String size , Set<String> colors ) {}`

Comment: [Your requirement doesn't make sense.](https://xyproblem.info/) A map is not a list of pairs. Each distinct key can only map to one value.

Comment: Edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the result should be `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`.
You can achieve this by grouping `name` and `shoeSize` in two steps and making the result a list of `Color`.
Try this.

```
record Student(String name, String shoeSize, String Color) {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> input = List.of(
        new Student("A", "8", "Blue"),
        new Student("A", "8", "Green"),
        new Student("A", "8", "Black"),
        new Student("B", "9", "Blue"),
        new Student("B", "10", "Green"),
        new Student("B", "10", "Black"));

    Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> map = input.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Student::name,
            Collectors.groupingBy(Student::shoeSize,
                Collectors.mapping(Student::Color, Collectors.toList()))));

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

output:

```
{A={8=[Blue, Green, Black]}, B={9=[Blue], 10=[Green, Black]}}
```