# Create a map of maps with counts from list

Tags: java, java-stream

Given a `List<Integer> l` and a factor `int f`, I would like to use a stream to create a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> m` such that the parent map has keys that are the index within `l` divided by f, and the value is a map of values to counts.

If the list is `{1,1,1,4}` and the factor is `f=2` I would like to get:

```
0 -> 
  {
   1 -> 2
  }
1 -> 
  {
   1 -> 1
   4 -> 1
  }
```

Basically, I'm hoping for a stream version of:

```java
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> m = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
 m.computeIfAbsent(i/f, k -> new HashMap<>())
  .compute(l.get(i), (k, v) -> v==null?1:v+1);
}
```

I realize it is fairly similar to [this question about collecting a map of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253858/java-streams-group-a-list-into-a-map-of-maps) and I understand how to do a much simpler `groupingBy` with a count:

```java
Map<Integer, Long> m = l.stream()
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

But I do not understand how to put those two ideas together without iterating.

Because I am working with indexes as one of the keys, I imagine that rather than starting with `l.stream()` I will start with `IntStream.range(0, l.size()).boxed()` which lets me get the first key (`i -> i/f`) and the second key(`i -> l.get(i)`), but I still don't know how to properly collect the counts.

Comment: So the index and not the value at index is divided by f?  And I don't know what you mean by counts?  What are you counting?  You might consider showing a hand written example of how the above resultant structure was arrived at for the data.

Comment: @WJS That's right: The parent map uses the index/f as the key. The second map uses the list value as a key and counts the number of values. In my example list, the value `1` appears twice for `index/2==0` so I map `0 -> 1 -> 2`.

Comment: Or maybe a better way of explaining it: Because of the way integer division works, the factor will basically divide the list into a number of sublists. The first `f` items will be sublist 0, the next `f` items will be sublist 1, etc. Then for each of those sublists, I want to create a map of values and counts.

Comment: So you have it working with your compute methods but you want a stream version, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks for your patience and apologies for my poor job explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   final List<Integer> l = List.of(1,1,1,4);
   final int f = 2;

   final var value = IntStream.range(0,l.size())
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i/f, Collectors.groupingBy(l::get, Collectors.counting())));

   System.out.println(value);
}
```

Not sure if this is a personal requirement, but sometime using standard loops over streams is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Very nice.  I agree that there is nothing wrong with the loop version.

Comment: Thank you. This appears to work for me. I would prefer to use the stream because the section of code I am adding to already initializes a few maps with stream collectors. I wanted to be consistent with the existing code base, but if there's a reason to _prefer_ the iterator, there is nothing stopping me from doing that.

Comment: Code consistency is valid reason afaiac. In this case, I would have use a loop or an intermediate object (holding i/f and l.get(i)) because I do not like having local variables in my collectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your grouping collector in `CollectingAndThen` collector which takes a downstream collector and a finisher function. In the finisher you can modify the values (sublists) to a map:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 1, 1, 4);
int fac = 2;

AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();

Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Long>> result =
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            i -> ai.getAndIncrement() / fac,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toList(), val -> val.stream()
                                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                                                                  Collectors.counting())))));

System.out.println(result);
```